# How can I find the peaks in python? I'm getting the indices. I want the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, maxima

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
a=[2,3,4,1]
b=find_peaks(a)
print(b)
```

I am getting the indices. But I want the values. How can I get the values of the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indices on the original vector to return the value of the peak like this:

```
a = np.array([2, 3, 4, 1])
peaks, properties = find_peaks(a)
a[peaks]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert `a` to a numpy array then index it.

```
a = np.array([2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 0], dtype=np.float32)
idx, props = find_peaks(a)
val = a[idx]

print(idx)  # this outputs [2 4]
print(val)  # this outputs [4. 5.]
```

Comment: My list doesn't contain integers. It is showing 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index'

Comment: @Abhilipsa. So what?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm unable to get the values

Comment: That's not very informative

Comment: @MadPhysicist The list should have only integers according to the error. But my list contains float values.

Comment: @Abhilipsa Your comment indicates that you are trying to access `a` with invalid indices. Are you splitting the output of `find_peaks` into its parts like I did in my example? `find_peaks` returns a 2-tuple, and only the first element of the tuple contains the indices of the peaks.